# Name of the numbers defined by $T(p,q) = T(p-1,q) + T(p,q-1)$?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I came across these numbers :
$$ T(p,q)= \sum_{k=0}^{q-1} {p+k-1 \choose p-1} + \sum_{l=0}^{p-1} {q+l-1 \choose q-1} \quad p,q \in \mathbb{N} $$
While trying to solve this recurrence relation : 
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
T(p,q) = T(p-1,q) + T(p,q-1) \quad \forall p,q \in \mathbb{N}^{*} \\ 
T(p,0) = 1 \quad \forall p \in \mathbb{N}^{*} \\ 
T(0,q) = 1 \quad \forall q \in \mathbb{N}^{*} \\ \end{array}
\right. 
$$
 As both the relation and the expression are fairly simple, I'm certain these numbers have been studied already, but I can't seem to find their name, or if they have a simpler expression.

Comment: Pascal's triangle?

Comment: Indeed, using Pascal's triangle it looks like the expression can be simplified to $T(p,q) = {p+q \choose p}$. Thank you.

Comment: I solved the problem with a bit different boundary values [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1266595/126489), and another poster mentioned Pascal's triangle there as well.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative resolution. I found my formula by counting the leaves of the recursion tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no in my knowledge a name for these numbers. Using the formula you have given, the sums can be computed and we can conclude that :
$$T(p,q)={p+q-1\choose q}+{q+p-1 \choose p}={p+q \choose p}$$

(when $p$ and $q$ are both positive)

Comment: Thanks to user72012 I found that this simplifies to $T(p,q) = {p+q \choose p}$ which, I guess, explains why they don't have a name. Thanks.